# r- how to remove a particular string from column values

Tags: r

[data-picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gbq2h.png) this is my dataframe and here i want to remove 'Full Name' 'Playing role' 'Batting Style' 'Bowling Style' text from column values. i have used strsplit and getting the error of "not applicable to atomic vectors". is there any other solution?

Comment: Try to use `gsub()` function to replace those values with blank. For your first column you need something like `x = "Full Name A B";
gsub("Full Name ", "", x)`, but to apply it to the full column. Seems that each column has it's own string to be replaced by blank, which makes things easy for you.

Comment: oh yes but if i have more rows then how will specify for every column value?

Comment: Rows will be ok, as `gsub` is vectorized. Each column will have it's own philosophy, which you have to specify. See my answer below as an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an example see this process:

```
# example data
x = c("Full Name A B", "Full Name F B")
y = c("Playing role G G", "Playing role G M")
dt = data.frame(x,y)

dt

#   x             y
# 1 Full Name A B Playing role G G
# 2 Full Name F B Playing role G M

library(dplyr)

dt %>% mutate_all(~gsub("Full Name |Playing role |Batting style |Bowling style ", "", .))

#   x   y
# 1 A B G G
# 2 F B G M
```

Comment: I have tested your code with `sub` and the regex `mutate_all(~sub("\\w+\\s+\\w+", "", .))`. It may be seen as more general and it works if there are **exactly two words** to remove.

Comment: @Aishaatique do you mean columns? 1 column with 100 rows still has 1 pattern to remove. 100 columns with 1 row might have up to 100 patterns to remove, right?